# Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop LTS unattended installation

Tags: 22.04, usb-installation, preinstallation, autoinstall

I am trying to search around for the Ubuntu 22.04 Desktop autoinstall (like the Windows ISO image. We could deploy on the Windows ISO image, and make it install automatically with our customization once we boot up.), but I only get the autoinstall for Ubuntu server without a graphical user interface.

1. How could we automate Ubuntu Desktop  22.04 installation without any user profile preset (I believe we do need to preset a user profile for Ubuntu server autoinstall)?
2. I tried the Ubuntu OEM installation, but is there any way to repackage/clone it to create a bootable USB for recovery purposes?

Comment: @user535733, I'm sorry about that. I'm asking for the Ubuntu Desktop LTS 22.04 autoinstall without any user profile preset and way to clone the image in ISO format (use to create bootable USB).

Answer (score 1):

There's the FAI autoinstaller, which provides the creation of custom ISOs and there's also the option to create a desktop installation ISO
See [Custom Ubuntu ISO creation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1463480/custom-ubuntu-iso-creation)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same recently just to make future reinstallations easier. It looks there is no auto install on desktop present but you can install ubuntu-server and then install ubuntu-desktop metapackage. Tbh there are some differences between desktop and server so it's hard to tell if it is a good long-term choice. PS. You do not need to rebuild whole isos, autoinstall metadata can be provided on a secondary disks (iso/vfat) as well. Cockpit allows unattended installations of ubuntu-20 vm's, perhaps path to explore.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).