# Custom Ubuntu ISO creation

Tags: system-installation, iso

I have a Deeplearning system running on Ubuntu 20.04 with Cuda, Cudnn, tensort and other packages as per my requirement. Alongside this, I have also installed our company's software on it.
Common specs for my machine are Intel i7 processor with Nvidia GPU.

I want to create custom ISO of this system so that I can save time on installations.

I have tried using cubic and clonezilla to create this iso but they both are not giving me the desired output.
Cubic gives me an iso file but cuda and its associated drivers are not included in the iso. On the other hand, clonezilla is just creating a clone of all directories and not an iso.

Is there any way in which I can create this Custom Ubuntu ISO?

Comment: If cubic is failing, have you considered filing an issue against it, so they can fix the issue?

Comment: I have used Cubic many times for producing custom Ubuntu ISOs and any package I have installed ends up just fine in the ISO.  Unfortunately, there isn't a lot in your question that would help us answer you.  I would recommend adding in details of things and the output of what you have tried.  If you feel that you have done it correctly in Cubic, then I agree with @popey above that you should file the issue against it.

Comment: "I want to create custom ISO of this system so that I can save time on installations."  the 1 stmt does not mean that the 2nd part is true. I would ALWAYS go from a vanilla ISO and create a post install script to install and config everything else. That would save time and is useable on more than just Ubuntu. A custom ISO is limited to its lifespan (1/2y, 3y, or 5y depending on the ISO).

Comment: If the computers are similar enough, and from your description I think so, then you can create a master OEM system (an installed system with all the tools installed), that you can clone to the other computers. See [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Ubuntu_OEM_Installer_Overview).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: Your goals may be much easier to achieve if you use .IMG files rather than .ISO files, See: https://askubuntu.com/q/1300540/43926 . You can still use Rufus, dd, Etcher, Disks or mkusb to install.

Answer (score 0):

There's a web based ISO build server from the FAI (Fully Automatic Installation) project available which also supports Ubuntu.

Comment: I guess you mean https://fai-project.org/. How to actually use it for Ubuntu requires some research.